# Like clause result in mySQLi

Tags: php, json, mysqli, sql-like

I have this code to filter the name I am looking for in a table row 'labs' with more than 16K results:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");

$text = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['term']);

$query = "SELECT name FROM labs WHERE name LIKE '%$text%'";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$json = '[';
    $first = true;
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        if (!$first) { $json .=  ','; } else { $first = false; }
        $json .= '{"value":"'.$row['name'].'"}';
    }
$json .= ']';
echo $json;
```

The problem is when I insert the first two or more letters into the input always show me the entire data in that table row, per example if I put `der`, I need that the result show me only the data with `der` in the name but now always shows me the entire row

Answer (score 0):

The minimum word length is set to 3 by default in InnoDB. This might cause it to return all result when you type in 3 or less character count. See the reference below. try increasing count

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html

If you want to match from left to right then you can use it like

```
$query = "SELECT name FROM labs WHERE name LIKE '$text%'";
```